# Complex integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-zt^2+2wt}dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, exponential-function, improper-integrals

The goal is to show this integral
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-zt^2+2wt}dt = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{z}} e^\frac{w^2}{z}$ for $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\Re(z)>0$ using the identity:

$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi x^2}e^{-2\pi ix \psi}dx = e^{-\pi \psi^2}
$ for $\psi \in \mathbb{R}$

I have proven in a previous far that the function is holomorphic as a function of $z$ on all of $\mathbb{C}$ but I'm not sure how to do this next part. I looked for a substitution that would help but I only know the substitution formula for real number so I cannot just replace the $x$ in the identity with some complex number.

Any help welcome :)

Comment: @metamorphy sorry it was a typo now it is correct

Comment: complete the square in the $-z t^2 + 2 wt$ exponent. let's see, they want $z t^2 - 2 wt = \pi x^2 + 2 \pi i \psi x + C$ to start, so we need to deal

Comment: You probably meant holomorphic as a function of $w$ on all of $\mathbb{C}$. Also, take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2185537

Comment: @Gary its definitely z

Comment: @leoli1 it is the same integral, but I am expected to use the method in the problem statement i.e. using the identity!

Comment: @citizenfour How do you define your function holomorphically for $z=0$ or $z<0$ (there is $1/z$ and a $\sqrt{z}$ in the formula for the function)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this is correct but it is my best shot:

We complete the square in the exponent:

$zt^2 -2xt = \pi x^2 + 2\pi \psi ix +C\\
(\sqrt{z}t-\frac{w}{\sqrt{z}})^2-\frac{w^2}{z} = \pi x^2 + 2\pi ix \psi + C$

This gives us a value for $C = \frac{-w^2}{z}$, a value for $\psi = 0$ and a substitution $t =\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{z}}x + \frac{w}{z}$ (this is the bit I am unsure of - can I substitute a real number for this complex one????) But this reduces the function down to:

$
f(z) = e^{\frac{w^2}{z}} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{z}} \int_{\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi x^2}dx
$

Using the identity given with $\psi =0$ we know the integral is one and therefore we get the result:

$f(z) = e^{\frac{w^2}{z}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{z}}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-∞}^∞ e^{-zt^2+2wt}dt= \int_{-∞}^∞ e^{-z(t-\frac{w}{z})^2+\frac{w^2}{z}}dt$$
$$= e^{\frac{w^2}{z}} \int_{-∞}^∞ e^{-z(t-\frac{w}{z})^2}dt$$
Take $(t-\frac{w}{z})=u$ the integral becomes
$$e^{\frac{w^2}{z}}\int_{-∞}^∞ e^{-zu^2}du=\sqrt{ \frac{π}{z}}e^{\frac{w^2}{z}}$$